# Use environment var in compiler arguments on a Flashbuilder project

Tags: actionscript-3, compiler-construction, environment-variables, flash-builder

In the compiler options of my flashbuilder project, i'm trying to do this :

```
-define+=CONFIG::dev,${MY_VAR}
```

As MY_VAR would be a variable related to the environment and not to the project (so each developer on the project can define his value of MY_VAR). I tried to find a way in flashbuilder, or by setting an os var in windows, but without success, any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can grab a value from the environment straight away but if you want to customize your data per dev, you can have them in the flex-config.xml file for each dev.

If you don't want to have it right into the flex-config.xml file, you can """concat/merge""" another XML config file with another command:
-load-config+=myfile.xml

More info on the different ways you can define them (inline or within the XML file):
http://blogs.adobe.com/flexdoc/files/flexdoc/conditionalcompilation.pdf
In action:
http://ditdahgames.com/2011/07/stupid-flex-mxmlc-compiler-tricks-part-1-conditional-compiling/

Fabien

Comment: Thanks a lot, just tried with a concatened xml, it works like a charm :)